# how to check whether each fibre of a morphism of schemes is reduced or irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $k$ be a field. Given a morphism of schemes
$\operatorname{Spec}k[T,U,V,W]/((U+T)W,(U+T)(U^3+U^2+UV^2-V^2))\to \operatorname{Spec}k[T]$. When is the fibre is reduced or irreducible?

I tried to solve it as follows.

The corresponding ring of the fibre at a point $y\in \operatorname{Spec}k[T]$ is $$k[T,U,V,W]/((U+T)W,(U+T)(U^3+U^2+UV^2-V^2))\otimes_{k[T]}\kappa(y)=\kappa(y)[U,V,W]/((U+\bar{T})W,(U+\bar{T})(U^3+U^2+UV^2-V^2).$$ $\kappa(y) $ is the residue field. But I don't know how to continue. Could anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: The polynomials cutting out your scheme as a subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^4_k$ are both divisible by $(U+T)$.

Comment: @user45878 Could you explain it in more detail? I don't learn much about subscheme and 'cutting out'. Thank you.

Comment: Let $f=(u+t)w$, $g=(u+t)(u^3+u^3+uv^2-v^2)$ and let $A=k[t,u,v,w]/(f,g)$, then we are considering $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ with its natural map to $\operatorname{Spec}( k[T]$. We can naturally consider $\operatorname{Spec} (A) \subset \operatorname{Spec} (k[t,u,v,w])$.

Comment: The fact that $(u+t)$ divides $f$ and $g$ translates into the geometric fact that $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is the union of the line $V(x+t)$ and the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ where $B=k[t,u,v,w]/(w, u^3+u^2+uv^2-v^2)$.

Comment: If we assume that $k$ is algebraically closed and $y \in \operatorname{Spec}(k[t]$ is a closed point, then the same argument should work on the fiber (since we are just choosing a value of $t$).

Comment: @user45878 Thank you. I try it by myself again. By the way, it seems that $k$ may be not algebraically closed.

Comment: I don't think that a general $k$ should be any kind of problem. You might need to consider the cases of characteristic $2$ and $3$ separately, though.